# Existence of zeroes of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by $f(x)=\cos(2x)+2x^3-3x$.

Apparently this function has *at least* one zero on the interval $[0,2]$. However, I do not see why. I have tried using the intermediate value theorem but it does not allow me to conclude - since $f(0)=1$ and $f(2)=\cos(4)+10$. Additionally, the derivative $f'(x)=-2\sin(2x)+6x^2-3$ doesn't seem to provide any additional information.

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: What is $f(1/2)$?

Comment: $cos(1)-5/4$? What information does that give me?

Comment: @Mandralis It's smaller than 0, while f(0) is bigger than 0. So the function has a root in the interval [0,1/2] and respectively in the interval [0,2].

Comment: Ah! I see! However, is there a more general way to arrive at such a result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(0) = 1$

$f(1) = cos(2) - 1 < 0$.

You get a zero between $0$ and $1$ cause the function is continuous and you have a positive and a negative value.

Comment: You should probably mention IVT.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you use a less than or equal sign for the second line instead of a strict inequality?

Comment: Cause I'm lazy, ofc it is a strict inequality, what is IVT?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem or something like this I guess. Of course every intermediate value is taken if the function is countinuous.

Comment: Here you are https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem